# Column and row highlighting not working with classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a table example that would be roughly what I am after, however so it doesn't conflict with other tables on the page I need it to affect classes and not the td and tr tags direct.

Is this even possible? If so the example I have below is what it should look like and the jsfiddle is what it is doing after changing to classes.

Example working:
http://codepen.io/rglazebrook/pen/nAzgy

```
<script>


$('td').hover(function() {
 $(this).parents('table').find('col:eq('+$(this).index()+')').toggleClass('hover'  );
});


</script>


<style type="text/css">

body {
   font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
width: 80%;
margin: 20px auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
text-align: left;
}
table tr, table col {
transition: all .3s;
}
table tbody tr:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
table col.hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}



</style>




<div style="width:700px;">

<table>
<col />
<col />
<col />
<col />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Birthdate</th>
  <th>Preferred Hat Style</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>Abraham Lincoln</td>
  <td>204</td>
  <td>February 12</td>
  <td>Stovepipe</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Winston Churchill</td>
  <td>139</td>
  <td>November 30</td>
  <td>Homburg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Rob Glazebrook</td>
  <td>32</td>
  <td>August 6</td>
  <td>Flat Cap</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</div>
```

jsfiddle not working (after change):
https://jsfiddle.net/pr007qy8/

```
<script language="javascript">
hideTag('LeftPane');
</script>





<script>



$('.data').hover(function() {
$(this).parents('.tble').find('col:eq('+$(this).index()+')').toggleClass('hover');
});


</script>


<style type="text/css">

body {
font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.tble {
width: 80%;
margin: 20px auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tble .header {
text-align: left;
}
.tble .rows, .tble col {
transition: all .3s;
}
.tble tbody .rows:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
.tble col.hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}



</style>




<div style="width:700px;">

<table class="tble">
 <col />
 <col />
 <col />
 <col />
  <thead>
   <tr class="rows">
  <th class="header">Name</th>
  <th class="header">Age</th>
  <th class="header">Birthdate</th>
  <th class="header">Preferred Hat Style</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr class="rows">
  <td class="data">Abraham Lincoln</td>
  <td class="data">204</td>
  <td class="data">February 12</td>
  <td class="data">Stovepipe</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="rows">
   <td class="data">Winston Churchill</td>
  <td class="data">139</td>
  <td class="data">November 30</td>
  <td class="data">Homburg</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="rows">
  <td class="data">Rob Glazebrook</td>
  <td class="data">32</td>
  <td class="data">August 6</td>
  <td class="data">Flat Cap</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add class to your table, for example `my-table`. And use it in js - `$(this).parents('.my-table')`.

```js
// CSS Newbie article here:
// http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-table-column-highlighting/

$('td').hover(function() {
 $(this).parents('.my-table').find('col:eq('+$(this).index()+')').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  text-align: left;
}
table tr, table col {
  transition: all .3s;
}
table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
table col.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Birthdate</th>
      <th>Preferred Hat Style</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Abraham Lincoln</td>
      <td>204</td>
      <td>February 12</td>
      <td>Stovepipe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Winston Churchill</td>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>November 30</td>
      <td>Homburg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rob Glazebrook</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>August 6</td>
      <td>Flat Cap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But isn't that what I've done in the second example? (One using classes)

Comment: @HTMellis It's funny :) You forgot to add jQuery in your fiddle. And toggle incorrect class `.toggleClass('.hover');` instead `.toggleClass('hover');`.
https://jsfiddle.net/y170chyr/ fixed.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class so that you can use it on all tables you want to apply this affect to, then you can change your css and js as follows to target only tables with this class:

```js
$('.hover-table').find('td').hover(function() { // only find tds in hover tables
  var currentTd = $(this);
  currentTd.closest('table').find('col:eq(' + currentTd.index() + ')').toggleClass('hover'); // I would use closest in case your table is nested
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.hover-table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.hover-table th {
  text-align: left;
}
.hover-table tr,
.hover-table col {
  transition: all .3s;
}
.hover-table tbody tr:hover,
.hover-table col.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, .2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="hover-table">
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Birthdate</th>
      <th>Preferred Hat Style</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Abraham Lincoln</td>
      <td>204</td>
      <td>February 12</td>
      <td>Stovepipe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Winston Churchill</td>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>November 30</td>
      <td>Homburg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rob Glazebrook</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>August 6</td>
      <td>Flat Cap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's better for what I need in the fact it doesn't target all tables on the page but the highlighting doesn't work in the columns?

Comment: Hi Pete, I've just put that into jsfiddle and the columns still aren't working, just the rows?

Comment: That works great.. i have no idea why it wasn't working for me before.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet.

```js
// CSS Newbie article here:
// http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-table-column-highlighting/

$('.myTd').hover(function() {
  $(this).parents('.myTable').find('.myCol:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.myTable {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.textLeft {
  text-align: left;
}
.myTr,
.myCol {
  transition: all .3s;
}
.mytBody .myTr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, .2);
}
.myCol.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 203, .2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
  <col class="myCol" />
  <col class="myCol" />
  <col class="myCol" />
  <col class="myCol" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="textLeft">Name</th>
      <th class="textLeft">Age</th>
      <th class="textLeft">Birthdate</th>
      <th class="textLeft">Preferred Hat Style</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="mytBody">
    <tr class="myTr">
      <td class="myTd">Abraham Lincoln</td>
      <td class="myTd">204</td>
      <td class="myTd">February 12</td>
      <td class="myTd">Stovepipe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTr">
      <td class="myTd">Winston Churchill</td>
      <td class="myTd">139</td>
      <td class="myTd">November 30</td>
      <td class="myTd">Homburg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTr">
      <td class="myTd">Rob Glazebrook</td>
      <td class="myTd">32</td>
      <td class="myTd">August 6</td>
      <td class="myTd">Flat Cap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```